# Simple nodejs http proxy fails with "too many open files"

Tags: node.js

Well, ignore it. I have opened an issue https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/793

Trying to run http://www.catonmat.net/http-proxy-in-nodejs

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var proxy = http.createClient(80, request.headers['host'])
  var proxy_request = proxy.request(request.method, request.url, request.headers);
  proxy_request.addListener('response', function (proxy_response) {
    proxy_response.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
      response.write(chunk, 'binary');
    });
    proxy_response.addListener('end', function() {
      response.end();
    });
    response.writeHead(proxy_response.statusCode, proxy_response.headers);
  });
  request.addListener('data', function(chunk) {
    proxy_request.write(chunk, 'binary');
  });
  request.addListener('end', function() {
    proxy_request.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
```

Fails after a huge number of requests with:

```
net.js:695
        self.fd = socket(self.type);
                  ^
Error: EMFILE, Too many open files
    at net.js:695:19
    at dns.js:171:30
    at IOWatcher.callback (dns.js:53:15)
```

node 0.4.2 on OSX 10.6

Comment: what version of node are you using, there has been many patches since 1.3 (where I believe this error started)

Answer (score 8):

You may be hitting your (default) maximum value of opened files in your operating system (for Linux it's 1024), especially if your are doing huge number of requests. For example in Linux you can increase this resource limit with [ulimit](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/ulimit.htm) command:

```
ulimit -n 8192
```

Comment: what does mean `8192`

Comment: it doesn't mean anything. It is only a number which defined by yourself by your needs. Actually 8192 is 8 times of 1024. If you receive too much nodejs websocket connection (for example 100K), then you need to increase this number to 1024*100*2 = 204800 at least.

Answer (score 3):

Resurrecting an old post here but I wanted to add my own answer for Ubuntu (couldn't get the ulimit command working :s ):

```
$ sudo vim  /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Add the following:

```
SOME_USER hard nofile SOME_NUMBER
SOME_USER soft nofile SOME_NUMBER
```

Replace SOME_USER with your user.  Replace SOME_NUMBER with a number higher than the limit that is causing problems.

```
$ sudo vim /etc/pam.d/common-session
```

Add the following:

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

Reboot your machine and the problem should be fixed :).