# Socket.io: How many concurrent connections can WebSockets handle?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am wondering if you have any data on concurrent connections to websockets? I am using Socket.io on Node.js server. How many clients can connect to socket and receive data without bringing my server down? 1000? 1000.0000?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17453704/276648

Comment: @Raynos I have a Corei7 8GB RAM 64-Bit with Debian, do you know how many ? I don't think so

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This highly depends on your hardware configuration, what exactly are you doing/processing on the server side and if your system is optimized for many concurrent connections. For example on Linux machine by default you would probably first hit maximum number of opened files or other limits (which can be [increased](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321432/simple-nodejs-http-proxy-fails-with-too-many-open-files/5323112#5323112)) before running into hardware resources exhaustion or similar scalability issues. Key resource may be the amount of RAM which can be allocated by your node.js program to keep concurrent connections opened and ability to receive new ones.

Comment: I guess the best method will be to bring my server down with loads of socket connections and see the stats.

Comment: @Pono What did you figure out?

Comment: @Pono maybe create a bunch of websockets from a local computer to connect to server, do you think this is feasible?

Answer (score 19):

http://blog.caustik.com/2012/08/19/node-js-w1m-concurrent-connections/

Check this blog. We use the same principle. Previously our nodejs server will crash after 100 concurrent connections due to hardware constraints. But after we move to Amazon EC2 it is now highly scalable.

Comment: Nice! But, what's the count for *WebSocket* (not "long-poll COMET") connections?

Comment: @3s2ng, How many concurrent connections can Amazon do? Because 100 is totally horrible to be frank...

Comment: @Pacerier depends on which instance you are in. micro should be able to handle 100.