# Web Sockets vs Interval Polling

Tags: java, spring, websocket, polling

I'm currently looking for the best fitting solution to handle notifications. My current options are either using websockets or just do a polling (only 1 request every minute, no long polling, no permanent polling)

I somehow have problems to find performance indicators for these methods. The result should be able to handle a lot of users in parallel without taking too much resources.

### Option A:

- Every 30 Seconds a request is sent to check if the users has a new notification

### Option B:

- Each users holds a websocket connection and is directly informed about a new notification

In the backend i'm using java spring with spring boot. Do you know any best practices or reference implementations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest to use option A since you just need a quick response  and dont want to deliver further information in real time. You also speak of many users so it should be less resource consuming to request user notifications in a certain timeinterval than keeping an open websocket for each user. it also depends on your environment.

have also a look here: [How many system resources will be held for keeping 1,000,000 websocket open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448061/how-many-system-resources-will-be-held-for-keeping-1-000-000-websocket-open)

Comment: Thanks for the link - it's really helpful!

Comment: I am with option A