# WebSocket vs. WebRTC server performance at large scale (1 million connections)

Tags: performance, sockets, websocket, webrtc, tcpsocket

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448061/how-many-system-resources-will-be-held-for-keeping-1-000-000-websocket-open) about WebSocket performance. The conclusion of this question was that:

> On today's systems, handling 1 million concurrent TCP connections is not an issue.
>
> We had to demonstrate several times, to some of our customers, that 1 million connections can be reached on a single box (and not necessarily a super-monster machine)
>
> With at least 30 GiB RAM you can handle 1 million concurrent sockets. The CPU needed depends on the data throughput you need.

I need to build a service that can connect to multiple peers at large scale. The traffic should be very minimal and mostly passing a small messages between the server and the client on real-time. It could be that some connections will be idle for a long time.

I wonder which protocol will give me better performance with less resources on those circumstances. I need to choose a protocol that has real-time capabilities, but also supported on web-browsers so I ended up with **WebSockets** and **WebRTC** (On WebRTC, the server will establish a WebRTC `DataChannel` to each peer via some signaling service).

**What's the performance of WebRTC at large scale comparing to TCP sockets?
Can it handle large amount of connection with less resources than TCP sockets?**

Comment: Sadly, the question seems too broad for this site, although it might fit [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com). On a practical note, the WebRTC is designed to be peer-to-peer and might require some extra overhead, so I would consider Websocket to have a better chance at higher performance (untested).

Comment: P.S. Another consideration might be the availability of clients. Websockets should be available on most (or all) machines, while WebRTC isn't. i.e., [WebRTC doesn't seem to be available for Safari web browsers](https://webrtc.org/web-apis/) while Firefox and Chrome have slightly different APIs.

Comment: @Myst when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gant So I wonder about the performance of WebRTC at large scale. Where can I get that information?

Comment: @gnat thanks for pointing this out - it's important and I always forget to mention this.