# Check PHP Websocket connection Limit

Tags: php, ubuntu, websocket

How can I check the connection limit on PHP Websockets? I mean, how many connections can my server handle.

I'm using ubuntu server.

Comment: Google is not working today? Or haven't you installed apache benchmark yet? If not: install it, and test your server to see if the number of concurrent requests is likely to be a problem for you. If so, look at caching (things like varnish, opcode caching, memcache, APCu, ... )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5695547/2115672 (It's about node.js/socket.io but also work for you.)